# tream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Cloud Firestore API has not

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Am having this issues pls guys help me
stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Cloud  API has not been used in project 76534794857 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firestore.googleapis.com/overview?project=76534794857 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry., cause=null}.

Comment: I got the same error, how did you manage to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you Enabled Firestore on the project? if this issue persists, you should contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact)